# What is the advantage or reason to declare a pointer to *this* object?

Tags: c++, oop

What is the advantage or reason to declare a pointer to *this* object?

Assume an object has a private variable "x".

I frequently see this code:

```
class_name<T> &ma = *this;
ma.x = 1;
```

instead of

```
this->x = 1;
```

or even simpler

```
x = 1;
```

Comment: I've never seen that, but it should be `this->x`.

Comment: the difference is `class_name<T> ma = *this;` makes a copy?

Comment: Can you provide a sample program?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand. It does not modify the object pointed by `this` it modify's a copy of the object pointed by `this`. It seems the code you are dealing with frequently needs to creates a copy of the object pointed by `this`, which is if not bad an unusual need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your class's base class is a template class, the `this` pointer becomes mandatory for referring to any members of the base class. This is why the first two versions might appear in such cases, and the third version would error out.

The first 2 versions are identical (after they have been fixed - see below) and are only differentiated in personal style.

```
class_name<T>& ma = *this; 
ma.x = 1;
ma.y = 2;
```

vs

```
this->x = 1;
this->y = 2;
```

As @chris points out, your 2nd version has a compile error, and in your first version, if you do not use `&` that **involves a copy** which means it is doing **something very different** (possibly **wrong**) since the changes would not affect the current object but a local variable which would be destroyed at the end of the scope.

In general cases involving no template base classes,

```
x=1;
```

beats all.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I thought that one is the preferred way or allows a programmer do more with the code. Let me ask you another question: What is the logic behind the requirement of using **this** pointer to access members of the class?

Comment: I want to reiterate that it is explicitly in only a few cases, one of them being if your base class is a template and you are accessing its members. [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html) has more information regarding the why. It has to do with when templates are parsed relative to the rest of the code.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY Another reason is to make functions like this make sense - `void SetX(int X){ X= X; // which X is the member?? use this->X = X }`